# Are the columns of A a linearly independent subset of $\mathbb{R}^{100}$?

Tags: matrices

I have a $100\times 100$  matrix with entries $a_{ij}=(-1)^{i+j}$. 
 Are the columns of $A$ a linearly independent subset of $\mathbb{R}^{100}$?

I can see diagonal entries are all $1$, and other are $1,-1$, please help how to proceed

Comment: Does the first column look like the third column?  How similar are they?  The phrase "checkerboard pattern" comes to mind.

Comment: Aren't there only two distinct columns?

Comment: Obviously NOT. As the matrix is singular.